# Continual Serial Port Reads

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a C# application that has one textbox that puts the data received on a selected serial port onto new lines as they come in.

I realise this isn't a specific question, but I have done a couple of hours search and can't even find out what to ask exactly from a coding point of view.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to read serial data continually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215741/c-sharp-read-only-serial-port-when-data-comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here, has examples of how to read and configure the baud rate, handshaking etc:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx