# How to keep continues watch on serial port on which device is connected?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I wanted some suggestions like i have 2 device attached to serial port and now for that 2nd device can send data at any time based on
user interaction with that 2nd device.

The data send by 2nd device would be routed through wifi device.So can anybody please guide me for this???

I want to keep continues watch on that 2nd device which can send data at any time.this 2 device will be connected on 1 laptop and i always want
to listen to this 2nd device which can send data at any time when user will interact with this 2nd device.

Any suggestion guys??

Comment: Kindly correct your question. You said, "2nd device will send data only on user interaction with the device." And again you said, "2nd device can send data at any time."
What do you mean when you say, "I always want to listen to this 2nd device"
Your device is communicating with COM port on your laptop that means, it is reading and writing to the port.

Comment: @Rudra:yup you are right.what i mean is user can interact with the 2nd device anytime so that means my 2nd device can send data anytime based on user interaction

Comment: How you want to keep an eye on your device? like, when it receives or sends a data, You want a notification?

Comment: @Rudra:i want to keep an eye on 2nd device when it receives data but problem is that data can come on any time on my 2nd time

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a user interacts with your program. Your device will start sending data. For every data sent or written on the OUT buffer, there will be a response to that on IN Buffer.

Start reading the device response every time you execute a command or write something on OUT buffer or send data.

Make a note of response you may receive from the device.(On successful submission of data, on failed submission of data, on receiving a data, exception).

Now, decide on the basis or response received what next you want to do. Put all the four condition in a single if statement and use OR, AND,NOT operation from 16 possible combination.

You can get a better response if you can post your original problem with CODE snippets or device name. (I assumed you are working on GSM Modem for sending multiple messages and receiving the response.)

Comment: Ok i have think 1 solution like i will have 1 windows service which will always run when my computer will start.now when my 2nd device will receive data i will have this event: mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);Reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215741/c-sharp-read-only-serial-port-when-data-comes