# Thread issue using a SerialPort

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

just a little issue here, with this code I succeeded to get the data from my serial port but when i want to see this data in a label, i've got this : 
System.InvalidOperationException : 'The calling thread can't access to this object because an another thread is owner'.
I'm not quit sure what is the dispatcher and how use it. Could you explain it to me ?

```
    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //init serialport comport
        SerialPort comport = (SerialPort)sender;
        // Shortened and error checking removed for brevity...
        if (!comport.IsOpen) return;
        int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        HandleSerialData(buffer, comport);
    }

    public void HandleSerialData(byte[] respBuffer, SerialPort comport)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(respBuffer.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in respBuffer)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        string hex2 = hex.ToString();
        hex2 = hex2.Substring(22, 8);
        EnOcean_Label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();
        EnOcean_Label.Content = hex2;


    }**
```

Comment: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{EnOcean_Label.Content = hex2;});`  Adds the execution to the originating thread's call stack.

Comment: Are you using wpf or forms?

Comment: For multi-threaded applications, the UI executes on a different thread. You'll have to invoke something through the dispatcher (or similar) to update the UI.

Comment: WPF i'll try your code thank you mate

Comment: This is because you are updating the 'EnOcean_Label.Content', which is in the main thread from serial data receiver thread. You may want to have a look at the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215741/c-sharp-read-only-serial-port-when-data-comes/16216052#16216052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void HandleSerialData(byte[] respBuffer, SerialPort comport)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(respBuffer.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in respBuffer)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    string hex2 = hex.ToString();
    hex2 = hex2.Substring(22, 8);
    //EnOcean_Label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>{EnOcean_Label.Content = hex2;}));

}
```

Comment: CS1660  C# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type // i'm afraid that doesn't work

Comment: Probably need to cast it as an `Action`.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it on the UI thread.

You are calling `EnOcean_Label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();` but that is not enough as it would just let you know if its the thread associated with the Dispatcher or not.

Better to call `Dispatcher.Invoke` which will guarantee that the code will run on the Dispatcher thread.