# Can not receive data from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

**[UNSOLVED]**

I am trying to receive and write data into a txt file, I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215741/c-sharp-read-only-serial-port-when-data-comes) and added eventHandler properly. The sequence of opening etc. are the same. However I can not receive data, even when I try to print (inside `SerialPort_DataReceived`)it does not nothing. I can not receive data.

> `p.CmdSerialPort.DataReceived` is always null whatever I change.

Can someone please help?

```
 class Program
{

    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort CmdSerialPort;
    private StreamWriter swLog;
    private DateTime lastComm = DateTime.MinValue;
    private UdpClient udpClient_Cmd;
    private volatile bool _enabled_Cmd;
    public static int Ethernet_Packet_Header_Length = 14;
    public IPAddress IP { get; protected set; }
    public int Cmd_Port { get; protected set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Parameters: ");
        Program p = new Program();
        p.IP = IPAddress.Parse("....");//IP

        p.CmdSerialPort = new SerialPort();
        p.CmdSerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        p.CmdSerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        p.CmdSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        p.CmdSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        p.CmdSerialPort.DataBits = 8;

        //takes port, ethernet and filename inputs
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] input = s.Split(' ').ToArray();

        if (input.Length > 3)
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input size!");

        string filename = input[2];//takes filename 
        //DEFAULT PATH ROOT
        String root = @".\\";
        string path_combined;

        filename += ".txt";
        path_combined = Path.Combine(root, filename);

        try
        {

            if (p.TryConnect(input[0]))//takes port name  eg.COM9
                p.swLog = File.CreateText(path_combined);

        }
        catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("File creation failed!", ex);
            throw argEx;
        }



        p.Cmd_Port = Int32.Parse(input[1]);//takes port number  eg.4667

        p.Initialize();

        Console.ReadKey();

        p.Close2();

        p.Close();


    }//end of main

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SERIAL PORT 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private bool TryConnect(string portName)
    {

        try
        {

            CmdSerialPort.PortName = portName;
            CmdSerialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);
            CmdSerialPort.Open();

            if (CmdSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {

                return true;

            }
            return false;

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return false;

        }

        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return false;

        }

    }

    internal void Close2()
    {
        if (CmdSerialPort.IsOpen)
        {

            CmdSerialPort.Close();

        }

        swLog.Close();

        swLog = null;

    }



    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        lastComm = DateTime.Now;

        if (sender is SerialPort sp)
        {

            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            indata = indata.Trim(' ').Trim('\n').Trim('\r');

            WriteToFile($"{CmdSerialPort.PortName}\t{lastComm}\t{indata}");

        }

    }

    private void WriteToFile(string v)
    {

        swLog.WriteLine(v);

    }
```

}

Comment: Your Program exits before it can read anything. You need to make it wait between `p.Initialize()` and `p.Close2()`. Try `Console.ReadKey()`, so it will run until "Press any key".

Comment: You should also handle `TryConnect` returning "false" ...

Comment: Which serial port are you trying to connect to (Com1, Com2, Com3, ...).  There is not place in the code where you are specifying the com number.  The UDP/IP connection code has nothing to do with the serial port.

Comment: @Fildor I updated my code according to your advice, it creates the file which means TryConnect returns true, however txt is still empty

Comment: @jdweng since I create endpoints and I put them thinking that the problem might stem from those. I give "COM3" from console

Comment: If you go to device manager on the PC is the com port Com3?  Make sure you set the baud rate the same as the device.  The normal settings are 8 bit data no parity and one stop bit.  Also make sure handshaking is turned off (hardware and software) they are obsolete.  Does the device work with the vendor supplied application?  The cable may be wrong.  If the device works with vendor software then we can rule out the cable.

Comment: ReadKey must be _before_ p.Close and p.Close2

Comment: @jdweng I checked it is COM3, I set the port settings as you said, I exchanged the cable from next lab, @Fildor I corrected, and I put a breakpoint near `p.CmdSerialPort.DataReceived`, it shows null, I don't see, why it is null, it should have receive the data.

Comment: It would be null if the device was not opened or if it was closed.   Put a break point on all open and close statements.  May be you are opening the port more than once.

Comment: It could be the cable.  Not all cables are the same.  Are you using a 9-Pin to 9-pin cable?  If so there are null modem cables (pin 2 connected to pin 3) and non null modem (pin 2 connected to pin 2 and pin 3 connected to pin 3).  So you may have the wrong type cable.  Are you using USB to serial port adapter?  The standard windows driver may not work and you need to install the vendor specific driver.

Comment: @jdweng I think the problem is software, I put `CmdSerialPort.DataReceived` in wrong places so it is always null

Comment: @Fildor according to the post I refer, `CmdSerialPort.DataReceived` should be declared before  `CmdSerialPort.Open(); ` so I put it inside` try` block just before  `CmdSerialPort.Open(); `

Comment: Yes, ok. But I am talking about `ReadKey`. If you put it after Close, your listeners and connections will all be closed before any event can even occur.

Comment: See msdn sample code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Fildor I already did it, I just wanted you notify what I discovered by myself, your point is different I know, thank you, I am still trying :/

Comment: could you provide an example for the s value?

Comment: @AdamNorman what you mean by 's' value

Comment: i mean the user input

Comment: @AdamNorman to consoloe I write "COM3 4334 exfilename", 4334 is port number, exfilename is the filename we want to save the data

Comment: why you removed the initialize function implementation?

Comment: @AdamNorman I thought it does not affect the problem since it is ethernet related